# Error "Se esperaban 0 argumentos, pero se obtuvieron 1.ts(2554)" al integrar Paypal a Angular

Tags: angular, paypal

Estoy integrando a angular PayPal para el pago de un producto, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

**Se esperaban 0 argumentos, pero se obtuvieron 1.ts(2554) en la función ngOnInit().**

Comparto el código de componente.ts:

```
export class CursodetalleComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(){}
  
  @ViewChild('paypal', { static: true }) paypalElement!: ElementRef;

  product={
    descripcion:'Curso catacion de cafe',
    precio:599.99,
    img: 'imagen producto'
  };
 
 ngOnInit(){
    paypal
    .Buttons({
      createOrder: (_data:any, actions:any) =>{
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units:[
          {
          description:this.product.descripcion,
          amount:{
            currency_code:'MXN',
            value:this.product.precio
          }
        }
      ]
      })
    },
    onApprove:async(_data: any, actions:any)=>{
      const order =await actions.order.capture();
      console.log(order)
    },
    onError: (err: any) =>{
      console.log(err);
    }
  })

    .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
  }

}
```

Comment: En caso de que no resuelvas el error generado puedes reiniciar el proyecto de nuevo e instalar los componentes necesarios a ver si se ejecuta de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar como referencia los ejemplos que proveen en el repositorio principal de [paypal-checkout-components](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/tree/main/demo) para que lo emplees en tu pagina.

```
class AppComponent {
    private createOrder(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '0.01'
                }
            }]
        });
    }

    private onApprove(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture();
    }
}
```

También te recomiendo que leas la documentación para que uses de manera correcta cada método junto con los parámetros para [**`CreateOrder`**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) como [`purchase_units`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=purchase_units&t=request) y otros.

Existe una librería de terceros en **angular** basada en el **SDK** de **JavaScript** que te puede servir de ayuda llamada [ngx-paypal](https://enngage.github.io/ngx-paypal/).